# accessing class data in main

Tags: c++, class, graph

I have a graph class:

```
#ifndef GRAPH_H
#define GRAPH_H

#include<list>
#include<iostream>
#include "global.h"

class Graph_{

std::list<Vertex> vertices;
int vcount;
int ecount;

public:
    void insert_vertex(Vertex vert);
    int routesearch(Graph_ *passed, Vertex *vert,  double distance, double curdistance, double safety, double minsafe, int startID);



};


#endif
```

Then in my main I try accessing the Vertex list in a graph I declared and it gives me an error:     8   IntelliSense: member "Graph_::vertices"  is inaccessible. Have no clue what to do because it works for all the other structs i've made like Vertex except for the class i made.

```
 #include "graph.h"
 int main(){
    Vertex dumb;
    Graph_ map;
    map.vertices.push_back(dumb);
```

}

Answer (score 2):

> it works for all the other structs i've made

`struct` has `public` default access level. `class` does not. Make the member `public` if you want access to it:

```
class Graph_{
//these two are private, because a class has private access level by default
    int vcount;
    int ecount;
public: // <<<--- public here
    std::list<Vertex> vertices;
public:
    void insert_vertex(Vertex vert);
    int routesearch(Graph_ *passed, Vertex *vert,  double distance, double curdistance, double safety, double minsafe, int startID);



};
```